# how could i use require() to read a local json file by just adding the local project json file path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, require

This is how I managed to be able to read the json file

posts.js file

```
const PATH = require('/Users/jorgesisco/Dropbox/Programming_Practice/Web_Development/PWJ/Module-8/Blog/pwj-module-8-my-blog-api/exercise/data.json');

class Post {
  get() {
    // get posts
  }
  getIndividualBlog() {
    // get one blog post
  }

  addNewPost() {
    // add new post
  }

  readData() {
    return PATH; 
  }
}
module.exports = Post;
```

Now in app.js I call the function and I am able to see the json file in postman.

```
// 1st import express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Post = require('./api/models/posts');
const postsData = new Post();

const posts = [
  {
    id: '1581461442206',
    title: 'This is a New Blog Post',
    content: 'This is the content! ',
    post_image: 'uploads/post-image-1581461442199.jpg',
    added_date: '1581461442206',
  },
];
// const result = posts.flatMap(Object.values);

app.get('/api/posts', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send(postsData.readData());//here I call the function to see json file in postman
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on http://localhost:3000'));
```

I think I shouldn't use the whole file path for the json file but when I just use something like ./data.json an error happen because it can't find the json file.

Answer (score 3):

For accessing the files from the same dir you need to pass `'./'` 
Example: `require('./data.json');`

for accessing the files from one dir out from current dir `'../'`
Example: `require('../data.json');`

For accessing the files from two dir out within different folder `'../../foldername/data.json'`
Example: `require('../../dataFolder/data.json');`

Answer (score 0):

The file path is referenced from the directory where you run the main code (app.js)

1. Move your data.json file inside the directory where your code is located. Let's say `main_code/datadir`. So, it looks like this now -

```
-- maincode
   -- datadir
      -- data.json
   -- posts.js
   -- app.js
```

2. Refer the file in posts.js code as `require('./datadir/data.json')`(Assuming `datadir/` is in the same path/level as your `app.js` code)
3. Run app.js

Comment: thanks dude! It works, but is that ok? check this: https://prnt.sc/ubos3z

should that json data be on the main project folder?

Comment: It can be anywhere on the filesystem, but keeping it within the project folder makes it easy to maintain. 

And, accept the answer if it helps, cheers !